# pywinauto print_control_indetyfiers not working

Tags: python, pywinauto

What could be the problem when the print_control_identifiers/dump_tree function does not return children when referring to an application window (it returns only one entry with the window name)?

I had no problem logging in to the application, but when I selected functions from the card, a new window opens and from then on I can't see the elements.

I using backend="uia"

Update:

```
app_uia = pwa.Application("uia")
window = pwa.findwindows.find_elements(title="Form1")[0]
app_uia.connect(handle=window.handle)
dlg = app_uia.top_window()
btn = dlg.child_window(title="tbSearch", control_type="Button")
btn.click() #clicked after 70 seconds

dlg.print_control_identifiers() # none display
```

the problem looks like it was looking for the controls for a long time

I will add that all application controls are visible on the Inspect.exe side

Comment: First 3 lines can be replaced with one: `app_uia = pwa.Application("uia").connect(title="Form1", timeout=10)`. Also `top_window()` is highly not recommended to use because it produces unstable results depending on which exact window is a top one at the moment. Better use this specification: `dlg = app_uia.window(ttitle="Form1")`

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I can combine the three lines into one, as in the example. I used "Top_window" because there is only one window in the application, but the issue still persists with listing the children. Adding this line, I received the button after about 70 seconds.dlg.child_window(title="tbSearch", control_type="Button").wait("ready", 80)

Comment: In `atspi` branch of the pywinauto repository we have experimental mode fully compatible with `Inspect.exe`, but more slow: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/1012

Comment: @VasilyRyabov can this parameter allow_magic_lookup=False affect the performance of children search?

Comment: If you use only `window` and `child_window` specifications, `allow_magic_lookup=False` should change the performance of your script at all. It only prohibits using `best_match` attribute access with typo resistant slow search. So it prohibits the slow search, but it doesn't speed it up. Because `child_window` with `control_type=` is faster. Just use it.